# Theme does not apply on programmatically added views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am setting some properties in my application theme, it looks like:

```
<style name="my_theme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

The theme is correctly applied for all views defined in the `layout` file of the `activity`.
But if I add a `view` programmatically in the `onCreate()` method, these `styles` are ignored.

So, I can't use the theme to style these `views`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: did u try adding in ur manifest file <application......
        android:theme="@style/my_theme" >

Comment: yes, the theme is set in the manifest file. As I have already said: it works perfectly fine with all the views defined in the layout xml

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create View programmatically, this View does not attach to any activity on creation, that's why theme not applied.

But you can try to get from activity and use LayoutInflater instead of create your View via constructor. I think in this way, activity theme will be applied into new View.

Please, if you will try, let me know about any results.